# Magento2 admin login error

Tags: php, magento

Recently, I installed magento 2 . Everything works well but I can't get access to admin. When I'm trying to log in, I get the message:

> You did not sign in correctly or your account is temporarily disabled.

I created new users

```
php bin/magento admin:user:create --admin-user="admin" --admin-password="11gtbAAjjjj*" --admin-email="example@gmail.com" --admin-firstname="Admin5" --admin-lastname="Admin5"
```

But still cann't log in, the users are not locked. 
The site worked well in the past.

Please help me to fix my problem

Answer (score 0):

You have to **Unlock** user using following command.

```
php bin/magento admin:user:unlock [user name].
```

Comment: Athur said that he created new user, new user can't be locked

Answer (score 0):

Facing this issue **You did not sign in correctly or your account is temporarily disabled.**

1. open your http://127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin/
2. go your database
3. reset admin_user column then check field **first_failure** and **lock_expires** 000.00.000
4. now save you time